# How to cleanly keep below 80-char width with long strings?

Tags: python, coding-style, readability, code-readability

I'm attempting to keep my code to 80 chars or less nowadays as I think it looks more aesthetically pleasing, for the most part. Sometimes, though, the code ends up looking worse if I have to put line breaks in weird places.

One thing I haven't figured out how to handle very nicely yet is long strings. For example:

```
#0.........1........2........3........4.........5.........6.........7.........8xxxxxxxxx9xxxxxx
def foo():
    if conditional():
        logger.info("<Conditional's meaning> happened, so we're not setting up the interface.")
        return

    #.....
```

It's over! Putting it on the next line won't help either:

```
#0.........1........2........3........4.........5.........6.........7.........8xxxxxxxxx9xxxxxx
def foo():
    if conditional():
        logger.info(
            "<Conditional's meaning> happened, so we're not setting up the interface.")
        return

    #.....
```

I could use line breaks but that looks awful:

```
#0.........1........2........3........4.........5.........6.........7.........8
def foo():
    if conditional():
        logger.info(
            "<Conditional's meaning> happened, so we're not setting \
up the interface.")
        return

    #.....
```

What to do? Shortening the string is one option but I don't want the readability of my messages to be affected by something as arbitrary as how many indentation levels the code happened to have at that point.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can split the string into two:

```
def foo():
    if conditional():
        logger.info("<Conditional's meaning> happened, so we're not "
                    "setting up the interface.")
```

Multiple consecutive strings within the same expression are automatically [concatenated into one, at compile time](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

```
>>> def foo():
...     if conditional():
...         logger.info("<Conditional's meaning> happened, so we're not "
...                     "setting up the interface.")
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (conditional)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       25

  3           9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (logger)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                2 (info)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 ("<Conditional's meaning> happened, so we're not setting up the interface.")
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 POP_TOP             
             22 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 25)
        >>   25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the `LOAD_CONST` for line 3, the bytecode for the function contains *one* string, already concatenated.

If you were to add a `+` to the expression, two separate constants are created:

```
>>> def foo():
...     if conditional():
...         logger.info("<Conditional's meaning> happened, so we're not " + 
...                     "setting up the interface.")
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (conditional)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       29

  3           9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (logger)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                2 (info)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 ("<Conditional's meaning> happened, so we're not ")

  4          18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('setting up the interface.')
             21 BINARY_ADD          
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             25 POP_TOP             
             26 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 29)
        >>   29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

Python does fold binary operations on constants at compile time (so `+`, `*`, `-` etc.), in the peephole optimizations for the byte compiler. So for certain string concatenations the compiler *may* also replace `+` string concatenation of constants with the concatenated result. See [`peephole.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/peephole.c#l465), for sequences (including strings) this optimization is only applied if the result is limited to 20 items (characters) or fewer.

Comment: While there is automatic merging, I still prefer adding a `+` for clarity. Anyway, +1.

Comment: ah nice, this just might be it. Out of curiosity is that done at parse time or runtime?

Comment: @nightcracker: The *compiler* merges the strings. With `+` you move the concatenation to run-time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ah yes, compiler indeed.

Comment: @nightcracker: Evidence added. Sorry, but you are wrong. With `+` there are *two* string constants, and they are added at run time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters counter-evidence: https://gist.github.com/nightcracker/5255760 They're equally fast.

Comment: @nightcracker: ah nice. i was wondering whether the compiler would be smart enough to handle adding constant strings together. not sure about better readability, though, don't you have to add `+ \` at the line break to make it work? that seems less nice, although more explicit, true.

Comment: @nightcracker: It seems that for *some* strings the compiler optimizes the string concatenation. For *this* case, the compile-time concatenation *does not happen*. I added a counter-counter example to your gist.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah ok. Either way, the performance argument is irrelevant either way IMO - unless we're talking about a performance bottleneck here. But I strongly doubt that this logger entry is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @nightcracker: Probably not. I must say I didn't expect the short-string-with-add-operator concatenation to happen, that was a surprise.

Comment: interesting stuff, for sure. it seems it's an optional optimization a python compiler can make. the string literal concatenation behavior is defined in the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) to happen at compile-time, though.

Comment: @Claudiu: Yeah, I found the code that executes the concatenation of string constants, it applies to any binary operator involving two constants, within a size limit.

Comment: @nightcracker: Found the peephole optimization, it won't apply to results over 20 characters long.

Comment: Interesting thing that Victor Stinner sent an e-mail to pyhton-dev today which is related to the subject here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-March/124954.html